# How do I use Mail.app search and replace without the mouse

Tags: macos, keyboard, mail.app, email, mouse

A recent update to Mail.app in Mac OS X changed the UI of the search and replace when composing a new message.  The old version could be driven 100% from the keyboard while the new one requires using the mouse to click the Replace check box as well as hitting the "all" and other buttons.

Is there a way to drive this interface without using the mouse?

Comment: Not at the computer right now, but does tabbing to the element (like the checkbox) then pressing space to toggle it work? Most of the interfaces in Mac are navigable by keyboard, they just aren't always immediately obvious.

Comment: No it does not.  That would be fine if it did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enable full keyboard access from System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts, you can focus the buttons by pressing tab and select the focused button by pressing space.

Comment: Ok.  I knew about this before but I'm afraid with this setting, I'm not going to like how the keyboard acts with other applications.  Let me play use it over the next week and see.

Comment: Oh.... Control-F7 changes this setting.  Hmmm... Now THAT has possibilities for sure.  Weird.  In Mail, control-F7 sometimes changes that control and sometimes it moves to the next control.  That looks like a bug.