# What are the short-cuts to click buttons on a MacOS message box?

Tags: shortcut

[image: Prompt on MacOS]

On Windows you can use the TAB key to switch between which button has focus then press space to click the focused button.

However, on MacOS, when presented with the dialog in this screenshot, I cannot seem to use tab to switch between the buttons I want to click. I can only hit RETURN to click the Save button, or ESC to click Cancel. But I have no idea how I can click the "Don't Save" button using just the keyboard.

How can I navigate/click buttons in a MacOS message box using just the keyboard (not the TouchBar, Mouse or TrackPad)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can achieve the same behaviour in macOS!

First, you need to do as follows:

1. Go to Apple > System Preferences > Keyboard
2. Select the Shortcuts tab
3. Tick the All Controls radio button (see below)

[image]

4. Now exit System Preferences

Once you've done this, you can use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to navigate the various options (incl. buttons) in Dialog boxes. In the screenshot below I've selected the <kbd>Don't Save</kbd> button.

[image]

Once selected, just press the <kbd>space</kbd> bar as you would in Windows!

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Weird that this is not the default. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It used to be that in the message box you show, the <kbd>return</kbd> key saves, the <kbd>esc</kbd> key cancels, and <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> does the "Don't Save".

However, this is apparently not universal, and may not apply in every box you get. Try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

You ca enable [Mouse Keys](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204434#mousekeys) in the Accessibility options and use the keyboard to move the mouse pointer around.

Or you can enable full keyboard access to all controls in System Preferences/Keyboard/Shortcuts — see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103618/how-do-i-use-mail-app-search-and-replace-without-the-mouse).

Comment: That seems like even more work than using a mouse/trackpad. Surely there is a better alternative for power users?

Comment: @CodeAndCats Yes, there is another way, and I’ve edited my answer to include it. Your question didn’t specify that convenience was the driver, so I gave the all-purpose way to use the keyboard instead of the mouse.